# How to manage policies in gpedit.msc in a workgroup server (Windows 2019) using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, group-policy

I am trying to create a powershell script to manage policies (Administrative Templates (Computer) / System) in gpedit.msc.

I want to manage these policies in windows 2019 server which is not part of any domain.

I know the registry keys for the policies but when I add or update this registries I dont see the corresponding changes in the gpedit.msc (gui).

Is there any way to manage "Administrative Templates (Computer) / System" policies in gpedit.msc which is in a Windows 2019 (workgroup) server using powershell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://4sysops.com/archives/administering-group-policy-with-powershell/

And: https://serverfault.com/questions/848388/how-to-edit-local-group-policy-with-a-script

From the post above, use **PolicyFileEditor** PowerShell module:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.0

Here is an example:

```
$RegPath = 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop'
$RegName = 'ScreenSaverIsSecure'
$RegData = '1'
$RegType = 'String'


Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $UserDir -Key $RegPath -ValueName $RegName -Data $RegData -Type $RegType
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. But I am looking to update local policies in workgroup servers (not domain joined) using powershell.

Example: how can I "enable" the policy "Administrative Templates (Computer) / System / Audit Process Creation" using powershell. I tried to update the registry key for this but this registry key change is not reflecting in the policy setting (gpedit.msc)

Comment: Hi Ron, got it, have you tried `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Audit" -Name "ProcessCreationIncludeCmdLine_Enabled" -Value 1`  then after that run `gpupdate /force` for the change to take affect.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I tried this. Command executes successfully but there is no changes in the policy and it is still showing as "Not Configured".

Comment: I found this using a PS module: https://serverfault.com/questions/848388/how-to-edit-local-group-policy-with-a-script

Install: `Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor -RequiredVersion 3.0.0`

Try that module and let me know if it works for you.